# SOQL query giving error in salesforce

Tags: soql, jquery, rest, sosl

I am running a sample query in salesforce using jquery +Ajax but one of the query is giving me an error.

query:

```
select id from document__c where id not in (select entityid from topicassignment)
```

Kindly let me know the cause and resolution:

Error running the query: error,

> Bad Request, [{"message":"Implementation restriction: TopicAssignment
>   only allows security evaluation for non-admin users when either (1)
>   LIMIT is specified and at most 1000 or (2) WHERE is specified and
>   filter on Id or Entity","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]

Comment: please show your query as an edit to the post

Comment: select id from document__c where id not in (select entityid from topicassignment)

Comment: @riteshjaiswal The error message explains exactly your choices on how to fix this. More detail at the bottom of the [TopicAssignment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_topicassignment.htm) documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free SOQL only allowed for Administrators which have "view all data" permission. Other wise you should restrict your query as:

> - Specify a LIMIT clause of 1,100 records or fewer.
> - Filter on Id or Entity when using a WHERE clause with "="

otherwise you will get the error

> Bad Request, [{"message":"Implementation restriction: TopicAssignment
>   only allows security evaluation for non-admin users when either (1)
>   LIMIT is specified and at most 1000 or (2) WHERE is specified and
>   filter on Id or Entity","errorCode":"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]

Comment: is there any way to find record with no topic except this query    ::               select id from ce_document__c where id not in (select entityid from topicassignment)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:
[Select entityId from topicAssignment where entityId in (Select id from document__c) limit 1000]